# How to convert below MongoDB query into PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

Below query worked fine in Studio 3T and Robomongo, But I want to convert it into PHP format,

Following is my query,

```
db.news.aggregate([
{
      $match: {  "_id" : "1" }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "comments": {
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$comments",
                "as": "comment", 
                "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$comment.status", "active" ] } 
            }
        } 
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "comments": {
            "$slice": [
                {
                    "$slice": [
                        "$comments",
                        {
                            "$subtract": [ { "$size": [ "$comments" ] }, 1 ]
                        }
                    ]
                }, -1
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```

I have tried below, But it giving error "`Error: localhost:27017: FieldPath field names may not be empty strings.`"

PHP converted sample:

```
<?php
        $commentsAggregate=array(
                            array('$match' => array("_id" => "1")),
                            array('$project' => array(
                                    "comments" => array(
                                        '$filter' => array(
                                            "input" => "$comments",
                                            "as" => "comment",
                                            "cond" =>  array('$eq' => array( "$$comment.status", 'active'))
                                    )))),
                            array('$project' => array(
                                "comments" => array(
                                '$slice' => array(array(
                                        '$slice' => array("$comments",array('$subtract' => array( array( '$size' => array("$comments")),1)))
                                        ), -1)
                                )))
                        );
$cursor=$collectionNews->aggregate($commentsAggregate);
```

Please help me to convert above query.

Comment: Fix this line `"$$comment.status"` in your code. There are two `$`.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove extra `$`. You see.

Comment: While remove `$` it gives an error "`The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: string`"

Comment: Maybe something's wrong in this line: `array( '$size' => array("$comments"))`

Comment: while removing this same issue occured.

Comment: Not sure what's going on here. I would probably try reducing the "array(array(...))" bits into "array(...)"?!

Comment: Also, I would attempt to reduce the stages one by one to see which one the offending stage is. It won't give you correct results anymore, of course, but at least you get closer to the problem.

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your problem. This doesn't look correct. `{
                            "$subtract": [ { "$size": [ "$comments" ] }, 1 ]
                        }` should be `{
                            "$subtract": [ { "$size": "$comments" }, 1 ]
                        }` & `array( "$subtract": array( array( "$size": "$comments" ), 1 ) )`

Comment: @Veeram: Well spotted! That's copied code from my (previsouly incorrect) answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792117/how-to-use-slice-a-filter-result-in-mongodb Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the latest PHP driver? Also, what's the query that ends up hitting the server? You can find out from the MongoDB logs once you've enabled logging: `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`

Comment: I am using php driver `1.6.14` and above query return { 
    "was" : 0.0, 
    "slowms" : 100.0, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}

Comment: I wasn't talking about the result of the setProfilingLevel call. ;) Now, you've enabled profiling. So you can run your PHP code again and in the MongoDB server log file you should see what the query is that MongoDB actually receives (the offending one) - this should give us a pointer towards where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks @dnickless for you help & support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message "FieldPath field names may not be empty strings" originates from [the server](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/b25e825ede4acd47bfdae25edef44c497ee2233e/src/mongo/db/pipeline/field_path.cpp#L52). Looking at the example PHP code you've provided, I notice that you're inconsistently using single- and double-quoted strings. In particular, these two strings stand out:

- `"$$comment.status"`
- `"$comment"`

PHP is evaluating variable references inside double-quoted strings. Assuming the local scope does not actually have a `$comment` variable defined, those strings are going to resolve to `"$.status"` and `""`, respectively. As evidenced in [this script and execution output on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/uBVFv), those examples should *at least* result in a PHP notice for an undefined variable (my local PHP configuration happens to report this at the "error" level). If you have no record of that error message, I would suggest the following:

- Check your [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) configuration.
- Ideally, you should report everything (`E_ALL`) in a development environment. Full reporting is also advisable for production, although there you would likely want to disable [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) (for security) and instead ensure everything is logged properly.
- If it turns out the error *was* logged, look into how it was missed while debugging this issue.

As for fixing the root cause, you should be mindful to use single-quoted strings when writing MongoDB queries/commands in PHP. There is a note about this in the [`MongoCollection::find()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php) documentation, but it's not something we repeat on every page, as PHP's [double-quoted string evaluation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) is outside the control of the driver.